# Docker Desktop for Mac: Cannot unset Preference “Securely store Docker logins in MacOS keychain”

Tags: docker, macos, devops, docker-desktop, dockerhub

I’m running Jenkins for MacOS (using Homebrew) and Docker Desktop on Mac v4.22.0 (117440).

When I try to push docker image to the DockerHub for Python app from Jenkins pipeline, during the authorization with the DockerHub, the Keychain is automatically opened on my Mac. It says:

```
Could not find keychain to save item "<my DockerHub user>".
```

with two options: `Deny` & `Reset to default values`. When I choose the second option i.e. `Reset to default values` it says that all my previous passwords, certificates etc. will be deleted, which I don’t want to happen. However, then I chose `Deny` option and the following error appeared and my pipeline failed:

```
Using the existing docker config file.Removing blacklisted property: authsRemoving blacklisted property: credsStore$ docker login -u <user> -p <password> https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `The authorization was canceled by the user.`
...
ERROR: docker login failed
Finished: FAILURE
```

Jenkinsfile snippet for pushing docker image to the DockerHub:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        ...
        stage("Push Docker Image") {
        agent any
        environment {
            HOME = "${env.WORKSPACE}"
        }
        steps {
            script {
                docker.withRegistry('', 'dockerhub_id') {
                    dockerImage.push()
                    dockerImage.push('latest')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
...
```

where `dockerhub_id` are my DockerHub credentials on Jenkins (it’s correct for sure).
I have also tried using `docker login` command with the suggested parameter from the above output `--password-stdin` but the same issue happened.
Running `docker login` from terminal on my Mac works fine.
Then I found these articles: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3774 & https://medium.com/@yuliakostrikova/macos-custom-registry-login-issue-2b70d052c88f
I cannot even see the preference “Securely store Docker logins in MacOs keychain” on Docker Desktop app to disable it. I have also tried removing `“credsStore”: “osxkeychain”` or changing it to `“credsStore”: “desktop”` in `~/.docker/config.json` file and restarting Docker Desktop but nothing helped.
I appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.